# Parallel Structure and sequence of tenses

Tags: tense, sentence-structure, sequence-of-tenses

> The resumé I **sent** to you **is** the most updated one.

If we talk about parallel structure, why is *sent* in the past tense and *is* present tense?

Comment: This was tagged [grammatical-structure] [sequence-of-tenses] in ELU. Obviously we don't have those in common.

Comment: Is 'I was, am, and always will be a supporter of Accrington Stanley' problematic (from a syntactic point of view)?

Answer (score 1):

The two clauses are not parallel. For them to be parallel, they would need to have the same grammatical structure. The main clause is:

> The résumé is the most recent one.

The reason the tense is present is presumably that it remains the most recent résumé.

The *I sent to you* is a dependent adjective clause qualifying *résumé*. The reason *sent* is past is presumably because the act of sending occurred in the past.

Since the clauses function differently from each other, there is no parallel construction here, and the question of keeping tenses consistent doesn't arise.